# Authentication to GCP in terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

We need to create gcp resources with terraform, but we are stuck at the terraform init stage while terraform tries to authenticate to gcp. We have already configured our backend and obtained our service account key but minifying (removing the extra lines in credential json file) the credential json and  exporting to GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS, doesn't work. How are you setting this value?

Comment: Does this help: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#running-terraform-outside-of-google-cloud? We would also need to see at least a part of the code.

Comment: I don't know if you are aware it's `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and not `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS` then try to keep the json key file as it is without reduction

Comment: @MBHAPhoenix are you passing the path to the json file or the actual content of the json file?
Passing the path works, but we dont want to checkout the credentials json file to git. We want to export the contents of the credential json file to `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and this is not working even after removing the extra lines

Comment: @edoc Is this a part of some CI-CD pipeline?

Comment: @MarkoE yes it is

Comment: It's the path. @edoc you're right using json key file is not recommended security wise.

Comment: @edoc Couldn't you then use GCP SDK to authenticate and use those credentials, like it's explained here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#running-terraform-on-your-workstation?

Comment: @MarkoE using the GCP SDK opens the gmail UI, there a --no-launch-browser option that prints out the url in the terminal, that you are expected to paste in the browser unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

- If you are in a local and controlled environment you can use GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and set it with the path to the JSON key file. But as discussed key files are bad practices security wise. An alternative is to authenticate using `gcloud auth application-default login` and you dont have to deal with key files.
- Another alternative is to use Google Cloud Shell which is already setup with the credentials of the authorised user opening the session.
- Finally for automated pipeline you can use Google Cloud Build where processes will be run using the authentication and the authorisation of the service account used by Cloud Build